# MySQL keep first occurrence of value set duplicates to 0

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I'm working with invoice data that has multiple line items for each invoice. The issue is that the tax field has the entire invoice tax value on each line item as shown below:

```
| Invoice | Item | Amount | Tax |
|---------|------|--------|-----|
| 1       | A    | 10     | 6   |
| 1       | B    | 20     | 6   |
| 1       | C    | 30     | 6   |
```

What I would want

```
| Invoice | Item | Amount | Tax |
|---------|------|--------|-----|
| 1       | A    | 10     | 6   |
| 1       | B    | 20     | 0   |
| 1       | C    | 30     | 0   |
```

So essentially I want to keep the tax value on the row with the first occurrence of the invoice number and then every occurrence of that invoice number after I want to set the tax value to 0. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window function `row_number()` to identify the "first" item per invoice, and a `case` expression to replace `tax` with `0` on other rows of the group:

```
select
    invoice,
    item,
    amount
    case when row_number() over(partition by invoice order by item) = 1
        then tax
        else 0
    end as amount
from mytable
```

If you wanted an `update` statement:

```
update mytable t
inner join (
    select invoice, item,
        row_number() over(partition by invoice order by item) rn
    from mytable 
) t1 on t1.invoice = t.invoice and t1.item = t.item
set t.tax = 0
where t1.rn > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Considerin the first occurence determined by the value of Item column, you can use an Update Statement with a self-join where only the least letter value won't be updated through use of inequality logic :

```
UPDATE tab t1
  JOIN tab t2   
    ON t2.Invoice = t1.Invoice
   AND t2.Item < t1.Item
   SET t1.Tax = 0
```

*P.S.: This method works also for **pre 8** versions of database.*

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=87b29a7a72cdf01bc768c7bf37a43e9f)</kbd>